# mapStateToProps always returns undefined in Redux despite initialized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to return a not undefined state in mapStatetoProps(FooterLink.js below) from reducer(footerreducer.js below).

I get only undefined in mapStatetoProp func for now.

How can it return "returned A" from reducer?

FooterFirst.js is a Component to connect reducer.

(Something is wrong with this as well, but I don't guess it causes undefined state. Perhaps...)

index.js is actioncreator.

FooterLink.js

```
    import {connect} from "react-redux"
    import {changeWindow} from "../actions"
    import {undefinedText} from "../actions"
    import FooterFirst from "../components/FooterFirst"
    const mapStateToProps =(state,ownProps)=>{
      return {
        text:state.text
      }
    }
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch,ownProps)=>{
      if (ownProps.text === `undefined`){
        return{
          onClick:()=>{dispatch(undefinedText(ownProps.text))}
        }
      }
      return{
        onClick:()=>{dispatch(changeWindow(ownProps.text))}
        }
      }

    const FooterLink = connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps
    )(FooterFirst)
    export default FooterLink
```

footerreducer.js

```
const footerreducer = (state,action) =>{
  if (typeof state=== 'undefined') {
    return Object.assign({},state,{
      text:"A"
    })
  }
  switch (action.type){
case `A`:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    text:`returned A`
  })
case `B`:
  return {
    text:`retruned B`
  }
case `C`:
  return {
    text:`returned C`
  }
default:
  return state
  }
}
export default footerreducer
```

FooterFirst.js

```
import React ,{PropTypes} from "react"
let x = 0
const FooterFirst = ({text,onClick})=>{
  if(!text){
    x = x + 1
    console.log(x)
    return <a text={text} onClick={e=>{e.preventDefault()
      onClick()
    }}>
    AAAA{text}
  </a>
  }

  return (
    <a text={text} onClick={e=>{e.preventDefault()
      onClick()
      }}>
      iefefer
  </a>
  )

}
FooterFirst.PropTypes ={
  text:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onClick:PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default FooterFirst
```

index.js

```
export const changeWindow  = (text_Now)=>{
  return { 
    type:`A`,
    text:text_Now
  }

}
export const undefinedText = (text_Now)=>{
  return {
    type:`Notext`,
    text:text_Now
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you reproduce this here: http://www.webpackbin.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import footerreducer in to FooterLink.

Comment: Finally it did work! I imported not footerrducer but rootreducer in to FooterLink. But why it worked is remained to be solved...